# Static website hosted on AWS S3 fails after Oauth authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Hosted a static website on AWS S3. The homepage loads great.

It has the Oauth2 google authentication added. While authentication it redirects to the callback url and throws the following error message.

The url is something like this:
https://library.test.com/callback#access_token=XXXXXXXXX

**The webpage shows this error:**

[image]

***Few more information:***

1. Its a subdomain added to route53
2. SSL added using the cloudfront
3. The response header shows the following message

   ***X-cache: error from cloudfront***

Comment: This is a simple error from s3 and shows the urI part doesn't exist in the bucket.

Comment: The flow is like the react app gets build and is deployed to s3. After Oaut authentication redirection I get this. The problem is what file is it looking those are the keys generated by Oauth. @JamesDean